# Chrome extension monetization (technical question)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I recently got into chrome extension development and I noticed three ways to generate revenue:

1. Free extension with Donation Button
2. Extension with Chrome Web Store Payment ([link](https://developer.chrome.com/webstore/money#:%7E:text=Chrome%20Web%20Store%20Payments%20is,Web%20Store%20Payments%20is%205%25.))
3. Custom payment (example: payment on your website)

In terms of technical implementation for accepting payments, the **2nd** option is the easiest because Google makes it easy to do. Disadvantages? 5% on transactions + I assume this will not work on Firefox extensions (***can someone tell me if I'm right?***)

I prefer to go for the third way where I accept payments on my website through Stripe (1.4% + $0.30 in Europe) and keep a firebase database of users that paid. Seems reasonable until I started overthinking it in terms of how I would implement that.

---

**My Implementation**

I just assume that to go with the third option I will have to implement some conditional rendering in the chrome extension. Basically just send an *XMLHTTPRequest* to my firebase database with the user's credentials (e.g: gmail account) and if the credentials match, show them the advanced features, if not show them the basic features.

For reference purposes, this is the XMLHTTPRequest I talk about:

```
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

// 2. Configure it: GET-request for the URL
xhr.open('GET', 'firebase-database-website/usergmail');

// 3. Send the request over the network
xhr.send();
// the response will be true for paid or false for not paid
// next: save the response in chrome.storage(????) to avoid making thousands of requests every time & speed up
```

However I believe that there is nothing to stop users from abusing this service, correct? For example, they could always use some javascript to make the extension work without paying for it.

Not that I'm really concerned about it, I just want to know if I am correctly implementing this or if there is something else I could do. Let's consider this an opportunity for growth. Advice and examples of implementations are more than welcome.

Comment: Anything that's implemented on the client can be worked around on the client. You need to make it dependent on something that only the server can do, and have the server check the credentials.

Comment: @Barmar I can totally understand this. My point is, how should I go about the conditional rendering bit? I need a more specific solution. I currently looked into an extension with 800 downloads and it saves the key in the chrome storage. Then, it checks against the other keys in background.js so it could also be manipulated. My question is if it can be done something to avoid that

Comment: Not really. You can try to obfuscate it to make it harder, but you can't stop someone who is determined to get around it.

Comment: Im looking at doing the same with my extension, what was your process when doing this?

Comment: @GrahamBillington just go with Chrome Web Store Payment and screw it.

Comment: @iulian Did you ever confirm this does or doesn't work for Firefox then?  I can't imagine it would.  For anyone still trying to make this impossible to circumvent, you can't use a "if valid user, render this" type style, even if a server is validating the user is valid, since they can always skip the check.  You'd need the server to actually *deliver* the content that is rendered instead.  i.e. always render content from the server.  If valid user, good content.  If not, perhaps a link to how to become a paying user?  :-)  This won't make sense for every application though.